# To get the category from the post list page

Tags: wordpress, categories

I do this for get the category name and i got the array

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 4 [name] => cinematography [slug] => cinematography [term_group] => 0 [avhec_term_order] => 1 [term_taxonomy_id] => 4 [taxonomy] => category [description] => [parent] => 0 [count] => 11 [object_id] => 2526 [cat_ID] => 4 [category_count] => 11 [category_description] => [cat_name] => cinematography [category_nicename] => cinematography [category_parent] => 0 ) )
```

For this i wrote

```
  $category = get_the_category();
  print_r($category);
```

Now how can i store the "[name] => cinematography" in a variable.

Comment: `$variable["name"] = $cinematography;` like this?

Comment: i want to store "cinematography" from the category name.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `$category` is the array you got there, then

`$cinematography = $category[0]->cinematography;`

https://drupal.org/node/1245956